# TeX syntax file not recognising bold-italic blocks

Tags: neovim, filetype-tex

Basically title. Text inside `\textit` and `\textbf` is correctly formatted in *italics* and **bold**, but if I nest one inside the other, the text takes the formatting of the outer command, as shown here

[image]

the bold-italic highlight group does exist and it's defined by

```
:hi texBoldItalStyle
texBoldItalStyle xxx cterm=bold,italic gui=bold,italic
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Can anyone confirm this is what they get as well?

Edit: I'm on macOS, running `neovim` inside alacritty with `termguicolors` set, and I'm using [Iosevka nerd font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/Iosevka) which has a bold-italic typeface.

Comment: Please include more details of the platform you're on. Which O.S. are you on? Are you on terminal or GUI? If terminal, which terminal program? Which font are you using? Often in these cases many of these details matter to check for support for attributes such as italics in Vim/NeoVim...

Comment: I just updated my question with all those infos.

Comment: It looks like the feature to support bold+italics was added in alacritty v0.4.0, can you confirm you have at least that version? (https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#added-4, feature introduced in https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/pull/2746). Changelog also mentions a `font.bold_italic` property to customize it, perhaps you need to set that appropriately?

Comment: The problem is not the terminal, I know that because a) bold-italic works fine in markdown, b) setting the highlight group to something like `hi texBoldItalStyle guifg=#00ff00` has no effect, which I think means the text inside both `\textit` and `\textbf` is not recognised as belonging to that particular highlight group.

Comment: Yeah looks like the syntax for TeX gets that wrongly, big time... Can I suggest that you install the [vim-scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) plug-in and use the `zS` command to inspect which syntax groups it sets for you? I'm guessing it's not getting to use the `texBoldItalStyle` (or `texItalBoldStyle`) which would select bold+italic correctly...

Comment: It sets `texMatcher texItalStyle texDocZone`, while italic and bold set respectively `texItalStyle texDocZone` and `texBoldStyle texDocZone`. If I invert the order of `\textit` and `\textbf` the result is the same except of course `texItalStyle` is replaced by `texBoldStyle`.

Comment: I also get weird, but different behavior. In my case, the `\textbf{...}` by itself already looks bold+italic. I noticed that installing the [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) package fixed the issue for me. I noticed it does change the syntax to improve it. Can you try it and see if it helps your case as well? (Let me know if that's the case, I'll write an answer with it then.) Thanks!

Comment: I'm already using vimtex. I also have `let g:tex_conceal = ''` in my `init.vim`.

Comment: Please incorporate all your findings to the question, [edit] it again to mention everything you found out so far. Btw, the author of vimtex often answers questions in this forum, so you might get his attention to this question if you mention vimtex more prominently. You might also consider filing an issue in vimtex's GitHub. Since it's tweaking the syntax rules for TeX, it's possible there's a bug there... Make sure you also mention which version of Vim or NeoVim you're using, since large part of the TeX rules are coming from the runtime shipped with it.

Comment: I've already filed the issue, it's the most recent one on the vimtex's github page. Once I get an answer there I'm going to update my question and hopefully post an answer.

Comment: The issue has been resolved [upstream](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1777). Should I delete the question?

Comment: Please don't delete it! Instead, post an answer indicating this was fixed upstream and add enough references to help others with the same issue be able to find the update that fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: But if it's now fixed upstream, how could anyone in the future have this problem again?

Comment: People don't always update to the latest version of plug-ins... Also, the fix is in vimtex, so if someone is looking for highlighting bold italic properly, the information that **vimtex supports it properly** is very valuable!

Comment: Right, I've been using vimtex the whole time and I forgot that the default syntax file gets it wrong too. I'll post an answer later.